# What are good sites to get software recommendations for photo management?

Tags: software, learning

It isn't here.  My request here has collected 4 downvotes.

It isn't softwarerecs.SE  In 28 days it got few view, no comments and no answers.

I don't think there is another SE that would be appropriate.

So what sites do you use when looking for something a bit less common that Photoshop and Lightroom

Since I can't delete this please vote to close.  Moderators -- if you can delete do so.

Comment: **Please** read [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) Discussion-oriented questions really don't work here. I appreciate that you're trying to figure out where to ask instead, but that's not an answerable question either.

Comment: It's not that we hate you or your question. This *format* has just over and over again proven itself to work poorly for questions which boil down to "here are my specifications — please find me a match". I don't know if you intend the irony or not, but *this* question has fundamentally the same problem.

Comment: You sound frustrated, which is understandable. But it's not like we can magically solve the underlying problem by wishing it different. This site *is* good at answering questions about technique and the practice of actually making photographs, so I do hope that you stick around for that.

Comment: [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photography-chat) may also be another decent place to ask about it too.  We can't easily handle this kind of thing in Q/A format, but that doesn't mean we don't have people who want to try to help.  It just makes more noise than signal for the goals of something like SE.

Comment: For the asset management part - I'd also recommend you try the asking where the marketing team of a mid-large size company hangs out. IE: LinkedIn. I don't have a software rec that I can give, but it seems to me the type of person using such asset management software could be found where CTO's and CMO's hang out.

Answer (score 4):

Really, it is Google. These things change so fast and are so individualized (you have a very specific list of requirements) that it's unlikely anyone but you can do the research. That's why the Software Recommendation Stack Exchange isn't working so well, and it's why this type of question is in general off-topic across the whole network. It's not that it's an arbitrary rule against telling you what you want to know — it's that we know from experience that it does not work.

If you have about specific software features or how to use them, that's where Stack Exchange comes in.

Comment: I have spent *days* on google with this.  There are forum sites however that google does't index, or perhaps I'm using the wrong magic words.  So far the hits I get are either for enterprise generic DAM products, or for existing products that are not really DAMS, but only catalogs with very limited search.